# SQl Server Query against Server Group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I am using the tsql  code to run through a bunch of servers, and look in each database for the users. My issue that on a specific server, there are databases I do not have access to and do not need to use. When the query runs on them it stops on the entire server and moves to the next one. I have been trying to find a way to exclude certain databses from the search.

What I am trying to do is

for example on server A excluded these databses B,C,D, and so on . I have tried where <> and != and does not work or I have the wrong syntax

```
USE MASTER

If OBJECT_ID('#TDB', 'U') > 0
Drop Table #TDB

DECLARE @dbname varchar(200),
        @sql varchar(max)

CREATE TABLE #TDB (
DataBaseName nvarchar(200), 
UserName nvarchar(200)
)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE DBID>4
OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

SET @sql='insert into #TDb(DataBaseName,UserName)
select '''+@dbname+''' DataBaseName,[user_name] UserName FROM '+@dbname+'.[dbo].[USERS] where'+@dbname+'<>[APSSWATCH]' 

EXEC(@sql)

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname

END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

SELECT * FROM #TDB ORDER BY DataBaseName,UserName
DROP TABLE #TDB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for leading me into the right direction though, instad of

```
name<>'APPSWATCH'
```

I used

```
name NOT IN 'APPSWATCH'
```

and it works

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE DBID>4 and name<> 'APSSWATCH'
```

You can remove this one:

```
where'+@dbname+'<>[APSSWATCH]'
```